# how to write custom function and variable in jison?

Tags: parsing, jison

my lex code is

```
/* description: Parses end executes mathematical expressions. */

/* lexical grammar */
%lex
%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b  return 'NUMBER'
[a-zA-Z]              return 'FUNCTION'
  <<EOF>>               return 'EOF'
.                     return 'INVALID'

/lex

/* operator associations and precedence */

%start expressions

%% /* language grammar */

expressions
    : e EOF
        {return $1;}
    ;

e
    | FUNCTION '('e')'
      {$$=$3}
    | NUMBER
        {$$ = Number(yytext);}
    ;
```

i got error

```
Parse error on line 1:
balaji()
-^
Expecting '(', got 'FUNCTION'
```

what i want to pass myfun(a,b,...) and also myfun(a) in this parser.thank you for your valuable time going to spent for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[a-zA-Z]` matches a single alphabetic character (in this case, the letter `b`), returning `FUNCTION`. When the next token is needed, it again matches a single alphabetic character (`a`), returning another `FUNCTION` token. But of course the grammar doesn't allow two consecutive `FUNCTION`s; it's expecting a `(`, as it says.

You probably intended `[a-zA-Z]+`, although a better identifier pattern is `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*`, which matches things like `my_function_2`.

Comment: Thank you Rici,I upvote your answer then how to assign variable too

Comment: @ßãlãjî: the lexer can't know whether an identifier is a function or a variable. So if your language has both, your lexer needs to identify "identifier" tokens. Im your expression grammar, you'll see that function calls are unambiguous. There are lots of calculator examples all over the internet, including some excellent ones in the Bison manual.

Comment: Rici ,I can,t find any article, can you share any link?

Comment: Here's the example in the bison manual. I suggest you read the full examples chapter, though: https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Multi_002dfunction-Calc.html

Comment: Thank you rici,This is what I want.